# What does "Company Distribution" mean on Google Finance's stock screener?

Tags: stocks, online-tools, google-finance

On the [Google Finance stock screener](http://www.google.ca/finance#stockscreener), what is meant by the term "Company Distribution", and what are the default values referring to? I googled "Company Distributions" but could not figure out how this term applies to stocks.

Comment: When you post links, please try and post friendly links (with a title) and not bare http:// links.  Thank you.

Comment: ok good i will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Company Distribution is attempting to show a histogram of how many companies fall within a given range so you can visualize the number of companies that meet a certain parameter.  For example if you move the "Market Cap" sliders so the minimum slider is just before the large rise in the distribution and move the maximum slider so it is just after the fall off in distribution, you can see that most companies have a market cap between ~5700 and ~141B.